# search if string exists in any value of array like indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, cookies

I have a cookie split into an array:

```
var cooks = document.cookie.split(';');
[dogs=bla, cats=sdfgh, cabbages=kjhgfdfg]
```

If I wanted to find the index of 'cats=sdfgh' I could use

```
cooks.indexOf('cats=sdfgh');
1
```

But if I wanted to search to see if the value cats has been set, how would I do that? `cooks.indexOf(find('cat='));` or something to that effect?

So without knowing the value of cats, how can I tell if it exists in the cookie?

And, how can I get the index number of that cookie?

Comment: you could do a simple loop, check each element, break if you find it

Comment: It's a lot easier if you use a helper function, [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) has a little cookie framework and also a handy polyfill for [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) that lets you set and get cookies by keys

Comment: If the value of `cats` has not been set, would it be absent from the array, or would it look like this: `[dogs=bla, cats=, cabbages=kjhgfdfg]` or `[dogs=bla, cats=null, cabbages=kjhgfdfg]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could run a simple regular expression:

```
if(fun = document.cookie.match(/(^cats=|;cats=)([^;]+)/)){
    console.log(fun);
}
```

it will give you an array where the 3rd member is your value if it matches :)

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uz821ehg/1)

However, if you dont have to support shitty browsers its worth taking a look at the the MDN cookie framework referenced in the comments.

Comment: This is helpful thanks, simple solution. My bad though I shouyld have clarified. I'd like to know both if there is a match and then if there is, the index of that match in cook?

Comment: wouldnt your original solution still work for that?  indexOf returns -1 if not found,does it not?

Comment: Correct. But what my end goal is is to get the actual cookie returned if it's a match. So match would return 'cats=' whereas I would like to get 'cats=null'

Comment: @DougFirr oh you're saying you want the value of the cats cookie?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. My bad I should have reworded my original Q

Comment: see my updated answer.  I also changed the original regex because of cases like 'someCookie=ad;notCats=true' being positive matches.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I think your solution is useful if I know the value of cats beforehand, but I don't know what the value is. I think I'm gonna delete and repost. I probably just need a for loop but wondered if there was a shorter, more lazy solution. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to find the first matching value in array:

```
var cooks = document.cookie.split(';'); // ["dogs=bla", "cats=sdfgh", "cabbages=kjhgfdfg"]

var isSet = cooks.some(function(cookie) {
    return cookie.indexOf('cats') == 0;
}); // => true
```